# How can I use pd.read_html for scraping HTML tables with % values?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the 'Profile and investment' table from the following url: https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s=LU0526609390:EUR, using the following code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Define all urls required for data scraping from the FT Website - if new fund is added simply add the appropriate Fund ID to the List
List = ['LU0526609390:EUR', 'IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR', 'LU1076093779:EUR', 'LU1116896363:EUR']
df = pd.DataFrame(List, columns=['List'])
urls = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s='+ df['List']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url).content
    df = pd.read_html(r)[0]
    print (df)
```

However, when I use the `pd.read_html` function, I get the following error code:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100%'

because the table has entries in `%`. Is there a way to make Pandas accept `%` values?

My required output is to get a table with the following format:

```
    Fund_ID          Fund_type     Income_treatment     Morningstar category ......
LU0526609390:EUR        ...              ...                    ....
IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR        ...              ...                    ....
LU1076093779:EUR        ...              ...                    ....
LU1116896363:EUR        ...              ...                    ....
```

Comment: I recommend that you should use Beautiful Soup lib for parse the html and get the table by 'table' tab... put it back to the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the site uses the `'colspan'` attribute and uses `%` instead of with an int. As AsishM mentions in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69708014/how-can-i-use-pd-read-html-for-scraping-html-tables-with-values/69708349#comment123216785_69708349):

> browsers are usually more lenient with things like %, but the html spec for colspan clearly mentions this should be an integer. Browsers treat 100% as 100. [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan). It's not a pandas problem per se.

these should be in the form of an int, and while some browsers will accommodate for that, `pandas` is specifically wanting it to be the appropriate syntax of:

`<td colspan="number">`

Ways to approach this is:

1. Use BeautifulSoup to fix those attributes
2. Since it's not within the table you actually want to parse, use BeautifulSoup to grab that first table and then don't need to worry about it.
3. See if the table has a specific attribute and could add that to the `.read_html()` as a parameter so it grabs only that specific table.

I chose option 2 here:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define all urls required for data __scraping__ from the FT Website - if new fund is added simply add the appropriate Fund ID to the List
List = ['LU0526609390:EUR', 'IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR', 'LU1076093779:EUR', 'LU1116896363:EUR']
df = pd.DataFrame(List, columns=['List'])
urls = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s='+ df['List']

results = pd.DataFrame()
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), index_col=0)[0].T
    results = results.append(df, sort=False)
    
results = results.reset_index(drop=True)
print (results)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results.to_string())
0                      Fund type Income treatment       Morningstar category IMA sector  Launch date Price currency    Domicile          ISIN                                                        Manager & start date                            Investment style (bonds)                 Investment style (stocks)
0                          SICAV           Income   Global Bond - EUR Hedged         --  06 Aug 2010            GBP  Luxembourg  LU0526609390  Jonathan Gregory01 Nov 2012Vivek Acharya09 Dec 2015Simon Foster01 Nov 2012                                                 NaN                                       NaN
1  Open Ended Investment Company           Income       EUR Diversified Bond         --  21 Feb 2014            EUR     Ireland  IE00BHBX0Z19                         Lorenzo Pagani12 May 2017Konstantin Veit01 Jul 2019  Credit Quality: HighInterest-Rate Sensitivity: Mod                                       NaN
2                          SICAV           Income  Eurozone Large-Cap Equity         --  11 Jul 2014            GBP  Luxembourg  LU1076093779                                                                         NaN                                                 NaN  Market Cap: LargeInvestment Style: Blend
3                          SICAV           Income          EUR Flexible Bond         --  01 Dec 2014            EUR  Luxembourg  LU1116896363                                                                         NaN                                                 NaN                                       NaN
```

Here's how you could use BeautifulSoup to fix those `colspan` attributes.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define all urls required for data scraping from the FT Website - if new fund is added simply add the appropriate Fund ID to the List
List = ['LU0526609390:EUR', 'IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR', 'LU1076093779:EUR', 'LU1116896363:EUR']
df = pd.DataFrame(List, columns=['List'])
urls = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s='+ df['List']


for url in urls:
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    
    all_colspan = soup.find_all(attrs={'colspan':True})
    for colspan in all_colspan:
        colspan.attrs['colspan'] = colspan.attrs['colspan'].replace('%', '')
        
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup))
```

Comment: browsers are usually more lenient with things like %, but the html spec for colspan clearly mentions this should be an integer. Browsers treat 100% as 100. [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan). It's not a pandas problem per se.

Comment: @AsishM., valid point. It is more of an issue with the html. I was just pointing out that `pandas` was thrown off by the use of it not being `"100"`, but rather the `"100%"`. I'll adjust the wording in the solution.

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks again for helping me out with this, what would be best way to fix these attributes with beautiful soup in your opinion? Thanks

Comment: Just iterate through the elements with the `colspan` attribute, and replace the '`%'` with `''`. I'll add that at the bottom of the solution above.