# panda.read_html gives "No tables found" error

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import with pandas the tables in [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1v7qct2r5ud7a2/protein.html?dl=0). However, `panda.read_html` gives the `No tables found` error. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from unicodedata import normalize
import html5lib

pd.read_html(html_file_path)
```

I don't understand why it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: what is your full code ? can you add to the question ?

Comment: i think you should use dropbox [api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-get)

Comment: @Clegane the file is local, not in the Dropbox. I am using Dropbox just to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting a different error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100%'`. This is due to the fact that the html file uses the 'colspan' attribute with % (according to the html spec for colspan it should be an integer). One can fix this using what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69708349/2048279):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("protein.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

all_colspan = soup.find_all(attrs={'colspan':True})
for colspan in all_colspan:
    colspan.attrs['colspan'] = colspan.attrs['colspan'].replace('%', '')

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))
```